# Anyone know how mult works in coq?

Tags: coq

I am learning the basic part right now. And I found that the mult function contains plus as below:

```
Fixpoint mult (n m : nat) : nat :=
  match n with
    | O ⇒ O
    | S n' ⇒ plus m (mult n' m)
  end.
Example test_mult1: (mult 3 3) = 9.
Proof. simpl. reflexivity. Qed.
```

i unfold the mult and it showed

1 subgoal

______________________________________(1/1)

3 + (3 + (3 + 0)) = 9

I know that BC plus m and m is 3 so there are 3 times of plus. But I am curious where the 0 comes from. if this 3 means m, then where is n?

Thank you!

Comment: Doesn't the `0` come from "O ⇒ O"? And `n` turns into the number of steps in the expansion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should remember that 3 is a notation for `S (S (S O))`

When you ask for the computation of mult 3 3, only one step of mult, you get this:

```
mult 3 3 = mult (S 2) 3 = 3 + mult 2 3
```

Now if you compute mult 2 3 you get :

```
mult 2 3 = mult (S 1) 3 = 3 + mult 1 3
```

and then:

```
mult 1 3 = mult (S O) 3 = 3 + mult 0 3
```

and tnen:

```
mult 0 3 = 0
```

So the `0` that appears when computing `mult` comes from `mult 0 3`